# mongodb + silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Has anyone worked with mongodb from within Silverlight? What driver did you use? Silverlight supports only asynchronous sockets; but it looks like available C# drivers are synchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd probably be best to use the official 10gen [MongoDB C# driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center) on the server with a lightweight web API sitting over it that can be consumed by your Silverlight app with WCF, SOAP, REST, etc.

Comment: the problem is that we're developing [admin tool](http://mongoexplorer.com) for mongodb. So I don't want to use something special on server. But I like your idea, about using official C# driver. But it's better to use it on client via WCF RIA Services

Comment: I was looking at MongoExplorer the other day, looks great, nice work!

Comment: we use old driver(2009 year), and we had great headache while adopting it to async sockets of Silverlight! It would be great if we can somehow use official driver!

Comment: you all advice server tricks, but I think your ansver was the closest. Get your +50

Answer (score 4):

Believe it or not, my first project with MongoDB was in Silverlight.  IronPython, some C#.  This was in 2009 and we went live with something like 0.8 or 0.9 of MongoDB ... so it has been awhile.

This was I think 2.x Silverlight so it was harder to accomplish things like direct database connections.  That said, I would recommend still going the route that I went at the time.

Use a REST+JSON API on your server end and have your client communicate through that.  We did ours in Python, but there are these days a few awesome prebuilt Mongo REST Interfaces like [Sleepy Mongoose](http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2010/02/22/sleepy-mongoose-a-mongodb-rest-interface/) if you don't want to roll your own.

The biggest advantage of this is the question of security: with a direct database connection from client to server even with authentication you run the risk of the user getting into your database... at which point they can do anything they want as MongoDB Authentication restricts access at a DB level, but not what people can see or delete.  This doesn't even require disassembling code in some cases as there are, as I recall, development browser plugins that let you script a running Silverlight app from IronPython and IronRuby.

There are other reasons including the synchronous question, but overall I think having a serverside interface to Mongo with a clean, secured facade that talks to Silverlight would serve you better.

Comment: The problem is that the app we're working on is admin tool for mongodb. So no serverside interface is possible

Answer (score 1):

This not seems to be a good practice to access the mongoDB from silverlight.

I suggest you to wrap all your commands in a clean WCF service (maybe a data service), and completely abstract the mongo plumbing.

this will allow you to control exactly what kind of operation can be done, who can execute the command, and with an evolutive protocol.

Comment: hm. I don't understand your post completely. You suggest using something like WCF RIA Services?

Comment: not RIA services specifically, but at least having : mongodb <--> a custom service (WCF is one way to do that) <--> your app. In fact, you wrap the mongodb specific in a custom service

Comment: hm. I see. Maybe you can provide some link where similar solution is described? Is it possible to adopt some solution and still do not require anything except Silverlight to run the App? PS: please do not advice tricks on server-side as other do.

Comment: my suggestions means that you have to create a service at **server side**